# Unable to install angular-cli: EPERM -4048 unlink

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

when I try to install the angular cli through npm, it errors out. I was hoping someone here might be able to tell me how to fix it, or install it another way. The output from running npm install -g @angular/cli is as follows:

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for rxjs@6.3.3 (sha512-JTWmoY9tWCs7zvIk/CvRjhjGaOd+OVBM987mxFo+OW66cGpdKjZcpmc74ES1sB//7Kl/PAe8+wEakuhG4pcgOw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typescript@3.2.4 (sha512-0RNDbSdEokBeEAkgNbxJ+BLwSManFy9TeXz8uW+48j/xhEXv1ePME60olyzw2XzUqUBNAYFeJadIqAgNqIACwg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\typescript-4ae55f23\lib\fr\diagnosticMessages.generated.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\typescript-4ae55f23\lib\fr\diagnosticMessages.generated.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\typescript-4ae55f23\lib\fr\diagnosticMessages.generated.json']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\typescript-4ae55f23\lib\fr\diagnosticMessages.generated.json'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-4ae55f23\\lib\\fr\\diagnosticMessages.generated.json' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-4ae55f23\\lib\\fr\\diagnosticMessages.generated.json\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-4ae55f23\\lib\\fr\\diagnosticMessages.generated.json',
npm ERR!   parent: '@angular/cli' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-11T19_33_51_436Z-debug.log
```

I'm unsure of what is causing the issue, or how to go about fixing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Node version is: 10.15.1

NPM version is: 6.7.0

Comment: Are you running this as administrator?

Comment: looks like a permissions issue. if you are on MacOS, you can try installing through brew instead of using `sudo` --> https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/angular-cli
Another way around this is try using yarn instead

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution on github about angular cli's issues page

```
npm install -global typescript@3.1.6
```

(Mind you that installs version 3.1.6, you can install an upper version of your choice)

**Rerun command:**

```
npm install -global @angular/cli
```

**The above solve the error: WARN tarball tarball data for typescript@3.1.6 (sha512-tDMYfVtvpb96msS1lDX9MEdHrW4yOuZ4Kdc4Him9oU796XldPYF/t2+uKoX0BBa0hXXwDlqYQbXY5Rzjzc5hBA==) seems to be corrupted**.

Answer (score 3):

don't know about linux users but on windows this saved my life.
locate the npm folder at `c:/users/your user name/roaming/appdata/npm`
and do same for npm-cache in the same location
right click on it and uncheck read only checkbox and click apply, even though npm is not saying it directly i have found out that it is a permission issue and this worked perfectly for me