# npm install not working on angular throwing errors

Tags: angular, npm

I got a project where I am trying to do npm i which is not working and for the other peoples its working within one shot... i have checked all the node versions angular vesrions I dont understand what I am missing or my lap desnt supports?? dont know please hlep me
Hi All I have been trying to resolve this issue from few I almost tried all the ways to resolve but unable..pLease help me out.

For the first time npm install the below error

```
npm install
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typescript@2.9.2 (sha512-Gr4p6nFNaoufRIY4NMdpQRNmgxVIGMs4Fcu/ujdYk3nAZqk7supzBE9idmvfZIlH/Cuj//dvi+019qEue9lV0w==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm ERR! path C:\Desktop\Routing\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\node_modules\.staging\typescript-2f0799cb\lib\it\diagnosticMessages.generated.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\kishan babu\Desktop\Routing\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\node_modules\.staging\typescript-2f0799cb\lib\it\diagnosticMessages.generated.json'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\kishan babu\Desktop\Routing\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\node_modules\.staging\typescript-2f0799cb\lib\it\diagnosticMessages.generated.json']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\kishan babu\Desktop\Routing\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\node_modules\.staging\typescript-2f0799cb\lib\it\diagnosticMessages.generated.json'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Routing\\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-2f0799cb\\lib\\it\\diagnosticMessages.generated.json' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Routing\\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-2f0799cb\\lib\\it\\diagnosticMessages.generated.json\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Routing\\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\\noticeperiod-dev-frontend-master\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-2f0799cb\\lib\\it\\diagnosticMessages.generated.json',
npm ERR!   parent: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for http://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ETIMEDOUT: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/json-schema-traverse failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.19.35:80
npm WARN registry Using stale data from http://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
```

Does anyone face this issue.. pleasee..............

Comment: are you in correct project path to run npm install?

Comment: Follow-up as OP hasn't: I get this same issue. Seems this exact file has an issue, for the OP it's the `it` Italian version, for me it's the Brazillian Portuguese version, not that that should make a difference? I'm out of ideas as to what to try. 1) No other apps holding the file, 2) I'm running as Admin user.
Suggestions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638097/unable-to-install-angular-cli-eperm-4048-unlink/55487915

Answer (score 0):

In one shot it will fail just install your dependencies one by one

run

`npm i "typescript@2.9.2"` or `npm i typescript`

Answer (score 0):

Error: EPERM - indicates insufficient permissions.

Try to fix it, because NPM can not use the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

please check your folder project while doing npm

please try in different drive

or

give all access to that folder.